# Bing Maps - Cannot set and access Pushpins properties in the clusteredPinCallback

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a problem with the Bing Maps on the client side.

1. Markers on my map representing a building with the number of the apartments inside.
   I'm using custom Pushpin implementation - SVG image + text (number of apartments). Pins are rendering correctly.
2. I need to provide custom Clustering solution.
   Instead of displaying a Cluster Icon with the number of the Markers inside, I need to display a sum of all of the apartments inside the cluster grid.
3. I found that there is a map method called `clusteredPinCallback` which gives the access to the array with all of the markers inside each single `cluster grid`.
4. I'm trying to provide number of the apartments as a Pushpin options param for e.g. `text`, `title` etc., but none of them is correctly set.

```
const extendedPins = pins.map((pinItem, index) => {
        const options = {
                icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',
                title: 123,
                text: 123
            };

        return new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(pin, options);
    });


    clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(extendedPins, {
        clusteredPinCallback: createCustomClusteredPin,
        gridSize: 80
    });

    map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
});

const createCustomClusteredPin = (cluster) => {
  console.warn(cluster)
}
```

`console.log() response:`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two issues:

1. The text and title of a pushpin need to be strings and you are passing in numbers instead.
2. In `clusteredPinCallback`, the pushpin for cluster is already created, so you can just customize it through a `setOptions` call.

Try this replacing the same function in your sample:

```
function createCustomClusteredPin(cluster) {
    cluster.setOptions({
        icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',
        title: "123",
        text: "123" 
    });
}
```